# Is there any event fired when android View becomes visible within App?

Tags: android, android-layout

My App contains multiple views (scrollable), one of them is CustomView ( extends View), is there any android event fired when this View comes within visible area.

The approach i though of using background thread during the timeframe of `onAttachedToWindow` to  `onDetachedToWindow`
This thread will use `customView.getGlobalVisibleRect(rectangle)` to check whether any portion of the view is visible on the screen but this is spin lock approach, Is there any better way to detect visibility, any event which gets fired where I can call  `getGlobalVisibleRect`

Comment: see `ViewTreeObserver`

Comment: Have you tried `onVisibilityChanged()`? Put your check logic in the overridden `onVisibilityChanged()` method in your custom view to determine if the full view is visible.

Comment: You mean really visible to user on display or views's visibility set to VISIBLE?

Comment: Yes @skywall, visible to the user

Comment: You can obtain view's position within scrollview and implement  onScrollListener to your `ScrollView`. Then you are notified when your view starts to appear in display.

Comment: Yeah scrollView is one option but there are some activities which may not have scrollview, CustomView is provided through library  project ( my application is library project)

Comment: see `ViewTreeObserver`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is one sample code using **ViewTreeObserver**:

```
final View viewTemp = convertView;

convertView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
      int rowHeight = viewTemp.getGlobalVisibleRect();
      ...
   });
```

Notes:

- I don't know your code and it is not posted. The code `viewTemp = convertView` is just an example, code from using an Adapter.
- This is a listener when the layout is drawn for whatever reason which is many.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I would addOnScrollChangeListener too, addOnWindowAttachListener to cover few more cases

Comment: what if I don't have a reference to a view?

Comment: It is fired because the view is really visible in my case.

Comment: I think it's important to have in mind that you should remove this listener right after you've used it, so for this example, I would do so right after getting the rowHeight value, like this: `convertView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);`.