# Doing a task after a view became invisible

Tags: android, android-view, visibility, android-mediaprojection

I'm writing a screenshot app using Android `MediaProjection` Api in which an overlay button is shown on top of everything and user can click it to capture a screenshot anywhere. Since MediaProjection records screen content, overlay button itself is in captured screenshots. To hide the button when capturing screenshot, I tried to set view `visibility` to `INVISIBLE`, take screenshot and revert it back to `VISIBLE` but since **changing visibility is an async operation in Android, sometimes overlay button is still present in recorded shots**.

I Changed to below snippet and it worked in my experiments:

```kotlin
floatingButton?.setOnClickListener { view ->
    view.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    view.postDelayed(100) {
        takeShot()
        view.post {view.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    }
}
```

But it's basically saying I feeling good that in 100ms, button would be invisible. It's not a good solution and in the case of videos, in 100ms content could be very different from what user actually saw at that moment.

Android doesn't provide a onVisibiltyChangedListener kind of thing, **so how could I perform a task after ensuring that a view visibility has changed**?

---

#### Edit 1

Here's the `takeShot()` method:

```kotlin
private fun takeShot() {
    val image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage()
    val bitmap = image?.run {
         val planes = image.planes
         val buffer: ByteBuffer = planes[0].buffer
         val pixelStride = planes[0].pixelStride
         val rowStride = planes[0].rowStride
         val rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width
         val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                width + rowPadding / pixelStride,
                height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
         )
         bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)
         image.close()

         bitmap
    }
    bitmap?.let{
        serviceScope.launch {
            gallery.store(it)
        }
    }
}
```

The codes are inside of a foreground service and when user accepts media projection, I create `ImageReader` and `VirtualDisplay`:

```kotlin
imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(size.width, size.height, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2)
virtualDisplay = mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(
            "screen-mirror",
            size.width,
            size.height,
            Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.densityDpi,
            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, // TODO: DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC ??
            imageReader.surface, null, null
        )

mediaProjection.registerCallback(object : MediaProjection.Callback() {
            override fun onStop() {
                virtualDisplay.release()
                mediaProjection.unregisterCallback(this)
            }
        }, null)
```

I've tried without suspension and coroutine stuff and result was the same, so they most likely are irrelevant to problem.

Comment: Try [ViewTreeObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995545/is-there-any-event-fired-when-android-view-becomes-visible-within-app).

Comment: I tried to use AndroidX `View.doOnPreDraw` but had no success. Could you explain it more?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32778292/4168607 . This should work i guess .

Comment: I used the approach and by setting logs, I see that capture method (`imageReader.acquireLatestImage()`) is actually being called when overlay button is invisible, but it's still sometimes present in screenshots! 
It seems that `acquireLatestImage()` doesn't necessary give you "latest image". Timing is non-deterministic.

Comment: can you add the `takeShot()` method with question . Also check it in some other device .

Comment: @ADM Tried in another emulator and problem was there, too. Updated the question with more code

Answer (score 0):

Seems my problem is related to `MediaProjection` and that would be a separate question, but this question itself is relevant.

I ended up using this (almost copy-pasting core-ktx code for `doOnPreDraw()`). Pay attention that:

1. This doesn't work for View.INVISIBLE, because INVISIBLE doesn't trigger a "layout"
2. I don't endorse this, since it's GLOBAL, meaning that every visibility change related to "someView" view hierarchy, will call the `onGlobalLayout` method (and therefore your action/runnable).

I save the accepted answer for a better solution.

```kotlin
// usage
// someView.doOnVisibilityChange(become = View.GONE) {
//     someView is GONE, do stuff here
// }
inline fun View.doOnVisibilityChange(become: Int, crossinline action: (view: View) -> Unit) {
    OneShotVisibilityChangeListener(this) { action(this) }
    visibility = newVisibility
}

class OneShotVisibilityChangeListener(
    private val view: View,
    private val runnable: Runnable
) : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener, View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {

    private var viewTreeObserver: ViewTreeObserver

    init {
        viewTreeObserver = view.viewTreeObserver
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        view.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(this)
    }

    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        removeListener()
        runnable.run()
    }

    private fun removeListener() {
        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive) {
            viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        } else {
            view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
        view.removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(this)
    }

    override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View) {
        viewTreeObserver = v.viewTreeObserver
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View) {
        removeListener()
    }
}
```